How do I use the find() method to query a mongoose schema with an enum field (can hold multiple values (array)) that includes a particular value?
I have this schema:


const User = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mobile: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    roles: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["admin", "user", "student", "instructor"],
        default: "user",
    }
});



And I am trying to find all users that have roles that includes "student", users can have multiple roles like ["user", "admin"] or ["admin", "student", "instructor"] or ["student"] or ["user"] or ["user", "instructor"], etc

A standard Model.find({ key: value }) in MongoDB works the same way for an array as per the docs Query an Array for an Element so this will work:
const users = await User.find({ roles: "student" });

This will find the following documents:
{ firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith", roles: ["student"] }
{ firstName: "Sally", lastName: "Jones", roles: ["user", "student"] }
{ firstName: "Dave", lastName: "Brown", roles: ["user", "admin", "student"] }

If roles is indeed an array, so long as student is in the array it will match.



const User = require("@models/user");

const students = await User.find({ roles: /student/i });




There is no need to do a regex pattern match. This will result in a slower query.
